# How to fix problem with clicking event on bxSlider item in Chrome 73?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, bxslider

A bxSlider's inner item click event doesn't fire after Chrome has updated to version 73. How can I fire .on('click') event for elements in new Chrome?

It fires in Chrome when slides are moving. 
Everyting is fine in FireFox

```
<div class="slider-pager">
  <div class="slider-pager__item"><img src="1.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="slider-pager__item"><img src="2.jpg" alt=""></div>
</div>

<script>
        carouselProduct = $('.slider-pager').bxSlider({
            maxSlides:  3,
            minSlides: 3,
            slideWidth: 90,
            infiniteLoop: false,
            moveSlides: 1,
            slideMargin: 8,
            pager: false,
            nextSelector: '.slider__nav--next',
            prevSelector: '.slider__nav--prev',
            nextText: '→',
            prevText: '←'

        });
  $('.slider-pager__item').on('click', function (event) {
    //Don't fire in Chrome 73, works in FireFox
            $('.slider-pager__item').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');

        });
</script>
```

JS Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sergey_beloglazov/3ty7w12z/17/

**UPDATE:**
I have made a workaround for this slider, handling wrapper onClick event:

```
$('.slider-pager').parent().on('click', function (event) {
    var $hover_item = $('.slider-pager__item:hover');
    //Checking if we have found the element
    if ($hover_item.length>0){
        selectBxPagerItem($hover_item);
    }
});

$('.slider-pager__item').on('click', function (event) {
    selectBxPagerItem($(this));
});
```

**selectBxPagerItem()** - is a selecting function.
For a slider with colorbox on click, I have made a similar click emulation:

```
        $('.slider-for').parent().on('click', function (event) {
            var $hover_item = $('.slider-for__item:hover a');
            if (($hover_item.length>0)&&(!window.slider_for_click_imitation)){
                window.slider_for_click_imitation=true;
                $hover_item.click();
            }
            window.slider_for_click_imitation=false;
        });
```

**UPDATE 2019.07.20:**
I've  found out recently, that previous solution doesn't work now.
I've cheked it and discover, that inner elements have no **:hover** state;
So, there is another soulution with **mouseover** event

```
/* A Chrome bx slider bug workaround */

//A slide, that has the mouse pointer over
window.bxslider_mouse_over_slide=null;
$(function() {
    $('.slider-pager div').mouseover(
        function(event) {
            window.bxslider_mouse_over_slide=$(this);
        });

});
$('.slider-pager').parent().on('click', function (event) {
    //Check if we've got a slide under the mouse
    if ((window.bxslider_mouse_over_slide!=null)){
            $('.slider-pager__item').removeClass('active');
        window.bxslider_mouse_over_slide.addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Making a workaround, I've found out that when I click on banner, a **mouseover** event triggers, and only then it handles a click event. So that that moment slide has no **:hover** state. So I just save last hovered banner.
Check the solution: https://jsfiddle.net/sergey_beloglazov/5kmdacgn/22/

Comment: I have made a workaround for this slider:
```
        $('.slider-pager').parent().on('click', function (event) {
            var $hover_item = $('.slider-pager__item:hover');
            //Проверяем, нашли ли элемент
            if ($hover_item.length>0){
                selectBxPagerItem($hover_item);
            }
        });

```

Comment: I found this solution and it works:
"It works on Chrome when you add touchEnabled: false"
https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/3211737/links-are-not-working-in-chrome-inside-bxslider-but-working-fine-in-all-other-browsers?hl=en

но и ваше решение тоже работает

Answer (score 16):

Looks like the latest Chrome update made any click inside bxSlider target the container instead the link inside it.

Adding `touchEnabled: false` to the options disables the swipe behaviour, but solves the click issue. Eg.:

```
 carouselProduct = $('.slider-pager').bxSlider({
            maxSlides:  3,
            minSlides: 3,
            slideWidth: 90,
            infiniteLoop: false,
            moveSlides: 1,
            slideMargin: 8,
            pager: false,
            nextSelector: '.slider__nav--next',
            prevSelector: '.slider__nav--prev',
            nextText: '→',
            prevText: '←',
            touchEnabled: false
        });
```

I recommend keeping an eye/contributing to this thread for updates and better solutions:
https://github.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4/issues/1240

Comment: Thank you for your github link!
It's a pity, I didn't manage to find it with google, though I spend a lot of time searching for fix in internet
You can try https://www.google.ru/search?q=Links+in+sliders+aren%27t+working+Error+in+the+latest+version+of+Chrome - ther is no link to this page.

Comment: Also I had a violation in Chrome console every time I click on bxSlider image:
"[Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'touchstart' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952"
But I don't know, was it before update, or no. I'll try solution, may be it helps.

Comment: I tried "touchEnabled : (navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0)"
Violations in Chrome console had dissapeared, 
But banners  stopped moving by swipe on iPad. So I think It's not a complete solution. I won't use it. Also I read some people went on an old version of bxSliders, but I don't want that too.Other solutions concerns plugin code changing. It seems too risky for me.
My solution works fine, it fits me. So I have only some worries about violations in Chrome console now.

Answer (score 7):

I used the mousedown event instead

```
if(window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("chrome") > 0) {
    $("body").on("mousedown", ".bx-viewport a", function() { 
        if($(this).attr("href") && $(this).attr("href") != "#") {
            window.location=$(this).attr("href"); 
        } 
    }); 
}
```

Comment: This is the solution! Thanks