# link has been disabled , unable to client on link

Tags: html, css

In my website home page blog section we are displaying some blogs , by clicking that blog it will open in new page !

by hovering its showing link , but click is not working chrome browser (working fine in Firefox browser)

please check this image

[image: imagegorexplain]

i checked in CSS but i am not getting what is stooping this ,please let me how to fix this

Link: [webiste link](https://rejuvenatehealthretreats.com/)

Comment: I have a checked it's working fine

Comment: did you clicked on tittle or image ?

Comment: not working for me.. you have to show us code

Comment: oh yea its working in Firefox ! not in chrome  @LaljiTadhani

Comment: This will solve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320404/wrap-link-a-around-div

Comment: Works in IE 11, FF. Not in chrome. Intriguing.

Comment: Show code please.

Comment: Looks like problem with bxSlider, here the same issue with proposed solutions: https://github.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4/issues/1240

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is from 'bxSlider'

user this code

```
if(window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("chrome") > 0) {
$("body").on("mousedown", ".bx-viewport a", function() { 
    if($(this).attr("href") && $(this).attr("href") != "#") {
        window.location=$(this).attr("href"); 
    } 
}); 
}
```

reference : [referencelink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55389421/how-to-fix-problem-with-clicking-event-on-bxslider-item-in-chrome-73)

Answer (score 0):

> blogs, by clicking that blog it will open in a new page!

Add `target:_blank` on `a` tag

Comment: its not opening in same page as well !

Comment: It's not opening!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55389421/how-to-fix-problem-with-clicking-event-on-bxslider-item-in-chrome-73

Answer (score 0):

[image]

> you need to add target="_blank" on anchor tag like this see attached screenshot