# Problems opening hyperlinks

Tags: html, hyperlink

On our webpage some links can not be opened anymore. When hovered, the correct URL is shown in the little preview box in the bottom left corner. But when clicking the hyperlink, nothing happens. Strangely it works on mobile view.
Only the hyperlinks with the link text "Weiterlesen >>" seem to not work.
[image]

Any suggestions?
[Link to the page](https://wasserwiki.eu)

Comment: Works fine on FireFox. Ensure that you correctly escape `>` not to be treated as part of tag

Comment: Thanks four your answer. It really seems to work in firefox, though it doesn't in edge and opera. Also, it does not seem to depend on the ">". I removed them from the hyperlink  text but without success.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link to answer - [How to fix problem with clicking event on bxSlider item in Chrome 73?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55389421/how-to-fix-problem-with-clicking-event-on-bxslider-item-in-chrome-73)

There is a bug with bxSlider in chrome. You should set `touchEnabled: false` in order to use clickable links without your slider.

Comment: Wonderful! Works like a charm. I just set "touchEnabled: false". I wouldn't have figured this out by myself.

Comment: So this is a duplicate question and should be closed for that reason, not answered. [answer]

Comment: Ah, understood, I can see how to do that now. Thanks